# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when launching a pdf file on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to open a pdf file using the below working code I previously used on another app,

but this time I am getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when the flow hits this line: Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);

What is the meaning of this exception and how to get rid of it?

Please note that without caring about this exception (disabling it),

the file still cannot be opened.

Please note: the file exists in my isolated folder (checked with wpowertool),

I tried with 2 different files so it shouldnt be a matter of file corruption.

```
    public void openFile(string options)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("options: " + options);
        string optVal = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options)[0];
        asyncOpen(optVal);
    }

    public async Task asyncOpen(string filename)
    {
            filename = filename.Substring(2, filename.Length - 2);
            filename = filename.Replace("//", "/").Replace("/", "\\");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            Debug.WriteLine("local: " + local.Path);
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync(filename);
            Debug.WriteLine("pdffile: " + pdffile.Name);
            //// Launch the pdf file.
                Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile); 
    }
```

this [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1c780b47-fa0b-4fa5-9333-7a4102f7d820/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-when-launching-a-file-on-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required) belongs to me. Yes, the file is installed and I have acrobat reader.

Please note that this C# code is a [phonegap/cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html) which is called via javascript in my hybrid application.

Comment: Just so you don't get answers like: *does the pdf exist* and *have you got Adobe Reader installed?* you might want to clarify if [this MSDN post belongs to you](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c780b47-fa0b-4fa5-9333-7a4102f7d820/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-when-launching-a-file-on-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: if there was no file that I would have a "filenotfoundexception" or such

Comment: Yeah, I know and was just trying to save you from getting useless answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay attention to the remarks in this [MSDN Article - Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701471.aspx):

> The calling app must be visible to the user when the API is invoked.
>   **This API must be called from an ASTA thread (also known as a UI
>   thread).**

---

Huge ups to the OP for sharing the solution. The following code should help others get around this issue:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { asyncOpenFile(options); });
```

Comment: please how can I open it synchronously?

Comment: Edited and upvoted you because I'm seeing some [conflicts here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc0ea02d-1f40-4150-9f5b-f6c3049b6393/can-i-use-asynchronous-api-synchronously). A MS Employee say *Accessing the storage is relatively slow, and you* **shouldn't** *do it in the UI thread,* - **yet in the MSDN doco's is says you  SHOULD perform it on the UI thread**. Which one is it??

Comment: it works on UI, this way       Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { asyncOpenFile(options); });