# Xamarin.Forms app crashes because initial page was not created due to loading file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms WP8.1 app keeps crashing because the Initial Page was not created. This is happening because I'm calling an await method before creating the page and the app returns before the page is created.

I need to load some settings from file; which is an async operation. I cannot continue without it. Is there any way to stall the app on splash screen till the settings are loaded?

```
    public App()
    {

        try
        {
            InitDatabase();
            initAppconstants();
            initStyles();
            initUI();
            SubscribeToMessageCenter();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    private async void initUI()
    {
        await ApplySettings();
        // code to create pages
    }
```

`InitUI()` contains the code which creates the start page. The execution returns because of `await ApplySettings();` and then crashes as the initial page is not created

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31315711 - as per MSDN article don't use a non-UI thread to load a file... And the app has to be visible before using the API...

Xamarin is crashing  your app cause it can't handle it, but that's why it's happening.

Comment: OK cool, you're using the UI thread, good :) Can you please edit your question to confirm if loading the file AFTER the app is visible works? And does the screen load without loading the file? Are you using an Emulator a Device? When the app crashes is there any error message or any clues to aid troubleshooting? Also have you just tried a splash screen, that loads up and waits until the file is loaded?

Comment: Yes, the app is working fine, sometimes even with the existing code. The thing is, I want to load settings from a file and then set the labels according to the language obtained from settings.
Hence, I need to load the settings before the main page is created.

I've added image for splash screen from Visual Assets. I'm using a device. The exception says something like "Initial Page was not created"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error. I think I found its root cause and workaround for it.

I noticed that whenever I access ViewModel referrence in my XAML like below, it is not able to resolve referrence of my VM.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
     <xamFormsApp:MainViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

and to achieve above thing when I add reference of my class, it takes "MySampleApp.Droid" assembly referrence like below:

```
xmlns:myApp="clr-namespace:XamFormsApp;assembly=XamFormsApp.Droid"
```

But, if I move this binding statement to code behind and remove above assembly referrence like below, it starts working:

```
public AppMainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            BindingContext = mainViewModel;
        }
```

In Conclusion, to access code files created in shared project, Forms XAML needs Droid references (Its just my guess, based on what worked and what NOT). Maybe something is broken in XAML compilation.